# ToggleSwitch - Toggle to Edit, Toggle to Save

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, toggleswitch

I'm currently working on a Windows 8 app in C# and XAML, and I've decided to implement a ToggleSwitch to change the IsReadOnly property to **on** or **off** for certain text boxes.
If **off**, the text boxes should be IsReadOnly = true, which they are now. If **on**, they should be set to IsReadOnly = false, which they also do.

However, the main function of the ToggleSwitch is to save the new input in the text boxes once the ToggleSwitch has been toggled from **on** (not read only) to **off** (read only). By default, the switch is on **off** to ensure the text in the text boxes are safe.

In a shorter term:
1. Switch ToggleSwitch from **off** to **on** to be able to edit the text
2. Edit the text in the text boxes, or the text boxes you want to change
3. Switch ToggleSwitch from **on** to **off**, and the program will save the new text.

I have all the variables etc., and the program works fine, except that the ToggleSwitch doesn't save the new information, as I'm pretty clueless on how this should be done correctly...

Thanks, SOF.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want an all XAML way of doing things? Unfortunately DataTrigger isn't available in WinRT - you could try using VisualStateManager or just call a Save() method in the changed handler for your ToggleSwitch.

Comment: Hi. No, C# is by far preferred by me. I assume I'll have to try such a solution, then. Thanks :).